# Plotly Dash: Unable to link Dropdown with Graph

Tags: python, callback, plotly, dropdown, plotly-dash

I'm trying to use dropdown to filter a bar chart. However dropdown filter and graph works individually, I just can't seem to be able to link dropdown filter with my graph. I am new to Plotly Dash, could someone please help have a look at my code and tell me what and where the mistake I made? (attached below is my code). thank you very much

[image: this is the link to the screenshot of my code]

Comment: can you please copy and paste your code into your question instead of using a screenshot? this way, people can run your code locally to help you debug your problem

Comment: If you select multiple selections in the dropdown, the return value will be a list. So the initial value must also be a list. `value=['21102']` And I need the code to extract the condition with the value received from the dropdown. `dff = pti[pti['SA3'].isin(input_value)`

Comment: Thank you so much @ r-beginners :) it works now.

Comment: Good suggestion @ Derek O. I keep it in mind for my future posts